# Is there a way to make django admin actions list always visible?

Tags: python, django

On my django admin interface, I'm trying to make a command available all the time, my problem is that the actions list is only visible when there is at least one result in the list view. The idea is that, my command will create a bunch of models from an API request, so initially there might not be any. Any ideas on how to override this default behaviour?

I've already tried overriding get_actions (but that didn't display the list) and get_queryset (to return a fake queryset so that the change_list thinks there is at least one result) but none of them panned out

```py
class myBookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['pull_book_info']

    def pull_book_info(self, request=None, extra_context=None):
        call_command('pull_book_info')

    pull_book_info.short_description = 'Pull info from API'
```

So yeah, the idea is that I can select my 'pull_book_info' command even when there are no books in the list.

Additionally, it would be ideal if someone could shed some light into how to submit that command without selecting anything from the list below

EDIT: python 2.7 and django 1.11